# Javascript variables names which are reserved words

Tags: javascript

I find myself, for reasons which are too irrelevant to go into here but which involve machine-generated code, needing to create variables with names which are Javascript reserved words.

For example, with object literals, by quoting the keys if they're invalid identifiers:

```
var o = { validIdentifier: 1, "not a valid identifier": 2 };
```

Is there a similar technique which works for simple variable references?

A poke around the spec shows that there *used* to be a mechanism that allowed this, by abusing Unicode escapes:

```
f\u0075nction = 7;
```

However this seems incredibly dubious, and is apparently rapidly vanishing (although my recent Chrome still appears to support it). Is there a more modern equivalent?

Comment: For what reason are you trying to do this?

Comment: *"for reasons which are too irrelevant to go into here"* Maybe not as irrelevant as you think.

Answer (score 2):

If they're object keys, you can call them what you like (even reserved names), and you don't need to quote them.

```
var o = { function: 'a' }

console.log(o.function) // a
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9eq57b/)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more modern equivalent?

No. Reserved words cannot be used as variable names. You can use names that *look* like those words but that's it.

From the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-names-and-keywords):

> A reserved word is an *IdentifierName* that cannot be used as an *Identifier*.

---

FYI, reserved words can be used as property names, even without quotes:

```
var o = { function: 1 };
```

Comment: Regarding the last: my mistake, I tested it incorrectly. Regarding the former: still hoping that some strange phenomenon will crawl out of some obscure corner of the spec...

Answer (score 0):

Variable names can't be reserved words.

You can always do bad things like:

```
window["function"] = 'foo';
console.log(window.function);
> foo
```

You still can't reference it using a *bare* reserved, because it's reserved.

That it's machine-generated code means whatever is generating the code is broken.